# Saving uploaded video to file system hosted on a web server

Tags: objective-c, asp.net-mvc, xcode, file-upload

In a iphone mobile app, when a user is allowed to upload a video the app would then save that video in a file system, and save the name in the database. My question is how would/could I then access that video on a website version of the mobile app. I'd like to avoid using any webservices or wcf if possible.

In Step format:

```
  1. On iPhone app, user uploads video from photo library.
  2. That video is then saved to file system and name is stored in database.
  3. (?)User can then go online to website version of the app and see his/her videos that   he/she had uploaded from their iPhone.(?)
```

How can the file system be accessed? bc isnt' the  filesystem local within app? I would plan on accessing it via mvc app c#

Comment: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/StreamingLiveOrOnDemandVideoFromIIS7ToIOSDevicesIPhoneiPadAndSilverlightClients.aspx

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/resources/http-streaming/